# jquery mobile: $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false but does not freeze in android

Tags: android, jquery, ruby-on-rails, mobile

My app uses rails and jquery mobile. I used alert function to see the value of  $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled after been set to false, and it shows 'false' but still changes the orientation.

I tried with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false;  
        ........
});
```

and

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false;  
        ........
});
```

Is there a way such as  one code fits all to freeze orientation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misconception: `$.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled` is *not* meant to lock in your page's orientation, instead it relates to jqm's `orientationchange` *event* - see http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/